# one requirement in Engagement studio, Pardot

Tags: pardot

How to check mail response like reply to mail sent in engagement studio. for Open and click functionality is present , but i want info abt how to check if prospect responded/ replied to nurture mail sent or not?

Answer (score 0):

Native Pardot, not possible.

There are a few paths.

With one of the email integrations, we could hope that the sales team attached the email, and we can poll for it by Salesforce API, look for something unique, such as subject line, and if matched, add the prospect to a static list or tag, and now we can have engagement studio look for that signal to make the decision.

If we use a 3rd party email tool that gets data into SFDC (Or Pardot) we could follow the same pattern.